# Xamarin.Forms for iOS additional folder for logs with suffix

Tags: xamarin.ios

I`d like to have additional app folder.

Xamarin app on iOS creates folder in my case XamApp, but I want to have other one on same level called XamApp.Logs.

I know that there's temp folder which could be used for this kind of scenario, but I really need it as I specified because of usage of 3rd party library, which stores really big bunch of data to XamApp folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create folder in iOS, you could use the code below.

Creating a directory:

```
  var documents =Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
  var directoryname = Path.Combine (documents, "NewDirectory");
  Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryname);
```

For more details, please check the MS docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#application-directories

Comment: But I want to create folder on same level as "MyDocuments" which is just application folder

Comment: It cannot be available on iOS platform, iOS imposes some restrictions on what an application can do with the file system to preserve the security of an application’s data.
An application is limited to reading and writing files within its home directory (installed location); it cannot access another application’s files.